# What tense should I use?

Tags: tenses

My native language isn't English. What tense should I use to describe some actions/activities: present simple or present continuous? I don't mean actions/activities that are happening right now. For example what is the difference (in meaning) between these two sentences:

> 1) When you dream and you wake up and can't move.
>   2) When you are dreaming and you wake up and can't move.

Answer (score 1):

Both are ambiguous between two possibilities: are you dreaming about waking and not being able to move, or are you dreaming, and afterward waking immobile?

> When you dream and you wake up and can't move.

This construction implies a sequence of events: dreaming, then waking up. This isn't a natural way to say this, though. Try: *When you dream, and **then** you wake up and can't move*.

> When you are dreaming and you wake up and can't move.

The continuous construction implies that the dream doesn't stop at waking up - you wake up and can't move *inside the dream*. But even so, it's not the natural way to express this. Try instead: *When you are dreaming **that** you wake up and can't move*.

Comment: So if I use present simple , thins are in order for example
"When you talk and somebody gives you money" = you talk , stop , and somebody gives you money

"when you are talking and somebody gives you money"= you are talking , and somebody gives you money while you are talking/somebody gives you money but you dont stop talking 

Did i get it right?

Comment: I've edited, since I realized I wasn't clear that both constructions can mean both possibilities, they just *suggest* a certain interpretation. Simply joining two verbs with "and" does not tell whether the two activities overlap.

Comment: The real problem is treating "present continuous" and "present simple" as tenses. They're not. Present is a tense, like Past; there aren't any others in English. Continous is a construction, like Passive, Cleft, etc; there are thousands more in English. They are not the same thing and should not be treated the same, and their interactions are determined by context. Half of the questions we get here are about "present continuous versus present simple". They are always confused because their authors have been taught traditional garbage and it isn't working the way they were told it would.

Comment: @JohnLawler I fully agree. Do you see a contradiction in my answer? If so, I would like to rectify it!

Comment: No, not at all. Sorry if I gave that impression. I was just looking for a place to stick the comment. I'll probly put it on some others of the same ilk.

Comment: Those two sentences were just example , but basicly if I got it right  whenever i use ing-form(i think it's called infinitive? not sure) it means that the activity/actions continues right?
(I know it asked this in my first reply but i kinda haven't got any answer to it :/)

Comment: Yes, but in order to be definite about *how long* the action continues, it's best to be specific until you're comfortable relying on your assessment of the context.

Comment: Thank you very much , but what about activities where i can't determine if that activitie stops or continues for example:
1)I hate when i dream about dogs
2)I hate when i'm dreaming about dog